# Init.js failed to load in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I get the Init.js failed to load error when I click on the Share Point link.

It looks like there is some issue in loading the page.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fcC6.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you have any scripts running globally via the master page or specifically on that page - disable them first.
If you have any solution (your custom code / feature) running on your SharePoint, go to site settings >> site features (or site collection features in site collection settings) and disable it.
Then, open the page in browser debugger (F12 in browser) and in "exception behavior" choose "break on all exceptions".
This will show you exactly where the error occurs.